A Question about What's Wrong with My Computation of Polar Equation of a Hyperbola Centered at its Right Focus
I am trying to compute the polar equation of a hyperbola which uses the right focus $F_2$ as the center of the coordinates, but the result I got is wrong. Here is my solution:

Given the euqation of a hyperbola
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$
if we shift the center of the coordinates from the origin $(0,0)$ to the right focus $F_2: (c,0)=(\sqrt{a^2 + b^2},0)$, then the center of the hyperbola will be located to the left of the new origin $F_2$, so the new equation of the hyperbola is
$$ \frac{(x+c)^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1        $$
which is equivalent to
\begin{equation} \frac{(x+ae)^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{a^2(e^2 - 1)} = 1        \tag{8.1.1} \end{equation}
where $e = \frac{c}{a} \in (1,+\infty)$ is the eccentricity of this hyperbola.
Then, let $P$ be an arbitrary point on the boundary of the hyperbola, $r>0$ be the distance from $P$ to $F_2$, and $\theta$ be the angle formed by $P, F_2$ and $x-$axis, and we have $P: (r \cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta).$ And then, plug what we have now into $(8.1.1)$, we get
$$\frac{(r \cos(\theta)+ae)^2}{a^2} - \frac{r^2 \sin^2(\theta)}{a^2(e^2 - 1)} = 1$$
$$\begin{aligned}
&\Rightarrow (e^2 \cos^2(\theta) - 1) r^2 + 2ae(e^2-1)\cos(\theta) r + a^2(e^2-1)^2 = 0 \\
&\Rightarrow r = \frac{-2ae(e^2-1)\cos(\theta) \pm \sqrt{4a^2e^2(e^2-1)^2\cos^2(\theta) - 4a^2(e^2-1)^2 (e^2 \cos^2(\theta) - 1)} }{2(e^2 \cos^2(\theta) - 1)} \\
\end{aligned}$$
Since $r>0$ and $e-1>0$, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
r 
&= \frac{-2ae(e^2-1)\cos(\theta) + \sqrt{4a^2e^2(e^2-1)^2\cos^2(\theta) - 4a^2(e^2-1)^2 (e^2 \cos^2(\theta) - 1)} }{2(e^2 \cos^2(\theta) - 1)} \\
&= \frac{-2ae(e^2-1)\cos(\theta) + \sqrt{4a^2(e^2-1)^2} }{2(e^2 \cos^2(\theta) - 1)} \\
&= \frac{-2ae(e^2-1)\cos(\theta) + 2a(e^2-1) }{2(e^2 \cos^2(\theta) - 1)} \\
&= \frac{a(e^2-1)(1-e \cos(\theta)) }{e^2 \cos^2(\theta) - 1} \\
&= \frac{-a(e^2-1)}{1 + e \cos(\theta)} \\
\end{aligned}$$
But when I check the answer key, the answer is
$$\frac{a(e^2-1)}{1 + e \cos(\theta)}$$
which doesn't have the negative symbol.
So I am wondering where I made the mistake. Can somebody help check it and point out where the mistake is? Thanks!

Well, you say $r>0$ and then obtain $r = \cdots = $ something negative...  Maybe you should try the other sign on the square root...

Substituting $\theta=0$ into the answer key's formula gives a positive value, which seems problematic. I vote for your solution ... especially since plotting it gives the correct curve. :)

@Blue Wondering whether answer key is given for polar equation centered at the left focus.

@ZYX: "Wondering whether answer key is given for polar equation centered at the left focus." It is. The way I remember these focus-at-origin polar  equations is as $$r=\frac{p}{1\pm e\cos\theta}$$ where $p>0$ is the semi-latus rectum. I decide which sign I want for $\pm$ by thinking about what I'd want to happen with a parabola ($e=1$) in direction $\theta=0$. Using $+$ makes the point finite, while $-$ sends the point to infinity (because the denominator is $0$). Generally, $+$ (as in answer key's soln) puts the associated vertex (and directrix) to the right of the origin-aligned focus.

@Blue But it seems that $\theta$ cannot be $0$ and $\theta$ is always greater than some fixed angle. Wondering what it means to set $\theta$ as $0.$

@ZYX: When $\theta=0$, your formula gives a (correct) negative value for $r$, so that point of the curve is plotted "backwards" through the origin. (This is an important quirk of polar graphs that can take some getting-used-to. See, for instance, the animation in this old answer of mine.) If you setup a GeoGebra sketch or something to plot the hyperbola parametrically as $(r \cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ with your $r$ formula, you'll see that the left branch actually gets plotted for $\theta$ in a neighborhood of $0$ (bounded by the asymptote angle).

@Blue I realize what happens now: What I have got is the left half of the hyperbola, and I can use directrix to compute the right half. Maybe I really need shift my preference way from analytic geometry to plane geometry, otherwise I am feeling stupid of myself to not realize such simple thing.
